# How to change object name in ng-reapet dynamically in angularjs 1.5

Tags: angularjs

**Below is the dynamic directive (it is called in blade.php file)**

```
<div class="col l3 learners-selection-block" id="learners-selection-block">
    <dropdown-list 
data-name="Learner Type" 
data-label="Select Leraner Type" 
data-provider='{"adult_learner":"adult Learner","young_learner":"Younge Learner","parent_learner":"Parent Learners"}' 
data-provider-search="" 
data-provider-type="dataset"
data-class="learner-type-list" 
data-id="learner-type-list" 
data-search="yes" 
data-multiple="yes" 
data-keyword="learner-type" 
data-model-name="learnertype"
data-obj-name="learnertype" 
></dropdown-list>
</div>


<div class="col l3 learners-selection-block" id="learners-selection-block">
    <dropdown-list 
data-name="Learner" 
data-label="Select Learner" 
data-provider="getCompanyLearnersList" 
data-provider-search="searchNewCompanyLearnersList" 
data-provider-type="function"
data-class="select-learner-list" 
data-id="select-learner-list" 
data-search="yes" 
data-multiple="yes" 
data-keyword="learner" 
data-model-name="learner" 
data-obj-name="learner"
></dropdown-list>
</div>
```

**<-- below is the html code that will place on the above directive -->**

```
<div>
    <li ng-repeat="record in list_all_records" class="selection-list perf-elem" data-item-id="<%record.id%>" ng-if="search_key == undefined || search_key == '' || record.search_word.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_key) != -1">
</div>
```

**<-- below is the js code to create multiple directive -->**

```
app.directive('dropdownList', ['$filter', function($filter){
return 
  {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/controllers/get-drop-down-list.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        main_label: '@',
      },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      
      scope.main_label      = attrs.name;
      scope.select_label    = attrs.label;
      scope.css_class       = attrs.class;
      scope.css_id          = attrs.id;
      scope.label_keyword   = attrs.keyword;
      scope.list_all_records   = attrs.arrayName;

    },
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $attrs, $parse) { 

    }
  }
```

});

**Above code will create two drop down list.**

1. But "list_all_records" in ng-reapet remain same for all drop down
2. I want to change it "**learnertype**" on the place of "**list_all_records**" in first drop down
3. And I want to change it "**learner**" on the place of " "**list_all_records**" in second drop down" in second drop down

**So that I can print different-different data in learnertype and in learner**

**How do I achieve this modification.**

Answer (score 1):

**I tried and found a code. that is below and it is working for me well.**

```
<dropdown-list 
data-name="User Name" 
data-label="Please Select"                          
required ng-model="user_id" 
items="user_list" 
main-list="main_user_list" 
></dropdown-list>


<dropdown-list 
data-name="Product Name" 
data-label="Please Select"                          
required ng-model="product_id" 
items="product_list" 
main-list="main_product_list" 
></dropdown-list>
```

**Below Is the Html Code**

```
<div>
<li ng-repeat="record in items" class="selection-list perf-elem" data-item-id="<%record.id%>" ng-if="search_key == undefined || search_key == '' || record.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(title) != -1">
```

**Below is the directive code**

```
app.directive('dropdownList', ['$filter', function($filter){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/drop-own.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        items: '=',
        ngModel: '=',
        mainList: '=',
    },
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  
  scope.main_label      = attrs.name;

 },
 controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $attrs, $parse) { 

 }
```

}
});

**Finally declare your all dynamic directive variable in controller as you have added in directive**

```
app.controller('userController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window, $mdDialog) 
{

  $scope.user_list = [];
  $scope.main_user_list = [];
  $scope.user_id = [];
  
  $scope.product_list = [];
  $scope.main_product_list = [];
  $scope.product_id = [];

});
```